# How to setup a FTP user for IIS' FTP in Windows 7?

Tags: iis, windows-7, iis-7.5, ftp

I've setup a FTP server using IIS in a Windows 7 machine. I would like to add a user (I want several really, but if only I could add one I'd see if I can manage somehow with one), but the problem I find is authentication.

I can authenticate via the Windows user, which I wouldn't want (imagine 5 users, all 5 would need user accounts in the computer all of them password protected). I read about the IIS Manager Users, but it's not bundled in Client SKU's.

Is there any way I could add users to use the FTP functionality without having an account in the computer?

I read about using the management API from PowerShell to create users but I reached nowhere.

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, IIS's FTP will only authenticate against machine users unless you're running active directory somewhere and want to use that.

If you want an FTP service that has independent authentication, use a third-party FTP server.